# Как получить дату каждого дня указанного периода через парсинг?

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests

У меня есть парсер, который получает данные следующего формата json. Мне отсюда нужно вычленить только даты указанного периода. Т.е. получить список дат указанного периода.

```
import requests

url = 'https://investfunds.ru/etf/697/'
date_from = '01.04.2021'
date_to = '05.04.2021'
payload = {
    'action': 'chartData',
    'data_key': 'close',
    'date_from': date_from,
    'date_to': date_to,
}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print(r.content)
```

На выходе получаю:

```
b'{"name":"FinEx USA UCITS ETF (USD)","tooltip":{"valueDecimals":2,"xDateFormat":"%d.%m.%Y"},"data":[[1617224400000,5610],[1617310800000,5647],[1617570000000,5699]]}'
```

А нужно получить следующие даты, это те даты в которых есть цена.

```
['1.04.2021','2.04.2021','5.04.2021']
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто приведите данные в формате `UNIX timestamp` к типу `datetime`.

Пример:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

res = [DT.fromtimestamp(x[0] // 1000).strftime("%d.%m.%Y") for x in r.json()["data"]]
```

результат:

```
In [115]: res
Out[115]: ['31.03.2021', '01.04.2021', '04.04.2021']
```