# Мой парсер не забирает данные с сайта, не могу разобраться почему. Раньше все работало

Tags: python, парсер, get

Вот мой парсер. Его суть в том, что он парсит даты и цены стоимости актива указанного мой периода:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://investfunds.ru/etf/9705/'
date_from = '14.01.2021'
date_to = '02.04.2021'
payload = {
    'action': 'chartData',
    'data_key': 'close',
    'date_from': date_from,
    'date_to': date_to
}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
print(r.content)
```

Если раньше я получал какие-то хоть данные, то сейчас я получаю пустой список:

```
b'[]'
```

Не могу разобраться, что произошло и из-за чего все перестало работать.

Раньше на выходе получал:

```
b'{"name":"FinEx USA UCITS ETF (USD)","tooltip":{"valueDecimals":2,"xDateFormat":"%d.%m.%Y"},"data":[[1617224400000,5610],[1617310800000,5647],[1617570000000,5699]]}'
```

Comment: Ссылка на старый вопрос к этой теме:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266726/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3

Comment: выведите что сайт отвечает `print(r.status_code)`

Comment: @Дмитрий, код 200

Comment: Попробуйте добавить user-agent.По умолчанию запрос идет от "робота". Поищите информацию в интернете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проведя небольшое исследование данного вопроса я пришел к выводу что на сайте реализовали защиту от доступа к данным. Прежде всего запросы с самого сайта получают в качестве ответа `gif файлы размером 1x1` что само по себе подозрительно, но еще не достаточно для того чтобы подтвердить мои догадки.

Однако, изучив содержимое вставляемых тегов можно придти к выводу что информация передается именно таким образом. Ниже приведен cниппет для сравнения 2х изображений полученых при смене диапазона в графике катировок. Сами `gif файлы` при этом идентичны и внутри себя информации не содержат. Аттрибуты изображений включая событие клика (на **пиксель!** и записанное далеко не стандартным образом) так же не оставляют равнодушным. Но так как мое исследование было достаточно краким, не могу ничего утверждать на 100%. Получение изображений происходит именно в момент работы с графиком.

```js
const a = '<img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/clmap/51681923?page-url=https%3A%2F%2Finvestfunds.ru%2Fetf%2F9705%2F&amp;pointer-click=rn%3A80775702%3Ax%3A61905%3Ay%3A26809%3At%3A1973%3Ap%3A%C2%9018%C2%8AAA2A4A1A11AA%3AX%3A1112%3AY%3A1072&amp;browser-info=gdpr%3A14%3Au%3A1623031693599940360%3Av%3A551%3Avf%3Alvg2sn1re60e0fel%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ati%3A0%3Ast%3A1623031891&amp;force-urlencoded=1" alt="https://mc.yandex.ru/clmap/51681923?page-url=https%3A%2F%2Finvestfunds.ru%2Fetf%2F9705%2F&amp;pointer-click=rn%3A80775702%3Ax%3A61905%3Ay%3A26809%3At%3A1973%3Ap%3A%C2%9018%C2%8AAA2A4A1A11AA%3AX%3A1112%3AY%3A1072&amp;browser-info=gdpr%3A14%3Au%3A1623031693599940360%3Av%3A551%3Avf%3Alvg2sn1re60e0fel%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ati%3A0%3Ast%3A1623031891&amp;force-urlencoded=1" class="transparent">'
const b = '<img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/clmap/51681923?page-url=https%3A%2F%2Finvestfunds.ru%2Fetf%2F9705%2F&amp;pointer-click=rn%3A89440648%3Ax%3A20540%3Ay%3A40959%3At%3A1810%3Ap%3A%C2%9D1%C2%9018%C2%8AAA2A4A1A11AA%3AX%3A388%3AY%3A1080&amp;browser-info=gdpr%3A14%3Au%3A1623031693599940360%3Av%3A551%3Avf%3Alvg2sn1re60e0fel%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ati%3A0%3Ast%3A1623031875&amp;force-urlencoded=1" alt="https://mc.yandex.ru/clmap/51681923?page-url=https%3A%2F%2Finvestfunds.ru%2Fetf%2F9705%2F&amp;pointer-click=rn%3A89440648%3Ax%3A20540%3Ay%3A40959%3At%3A1810%3Ap%3A%C2%9D1%C2%9018%C2%8AAA2A4A1A11AA%3AX%3A388%3AY%3A1080&amp;browser-info=gdpr%3A14%3Au%3A1623031693599940360%3Av%3A551%3Avf%3Alvg2sn1re60e0fel%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ati%3A0%3Ast%3A1623031875&amp;force-urlencoded=1" class="transparent">'

console.log(a === b)
```

что касается парсера:

```
import requests
url = "https://investfunds.ru/etf/697/"
payload='''payload = {
  'action': 'chartData',
  'data_key': 'close',
  'date_from': '01.04.2021',
  'date_to': '05.04.2021',
  }'''
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload)
print(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

так возвращается страница, но я не уверен что там есть нужные данные,
хотя бы потому что на ней есть:

> Показано 0 из 0, уточните запрос
>
> Более 1000 записей, уточните запрос

Comment: Я могу вытащить цены с графика указанного периода? Или так как стоит защита это не реализуемо?

Comment: @ЕгорКопица я пологаю что скрипт который я предоставил будет возвращать одну и ту же страницу не зависимо от дат, то каким образом вытащить данные я не исследовал, для этого как минимум придется анализировать как это обрабатывается скриптами (трансформируется в данные) если это то что я думаю - шансов мало

Comment: @ЕгорКопица может быть платформа предоставляет возможность запросов, может покапать в этом направлении? Может найдется открытое API, все таки время такое, что все стараются предоставлять доступ к данным

Comment: то что API есть это скорее всего, другой вопрос бесплатно ли, вероятно что как раз по причине вала запросов и меняли доступ.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, а если использовать fake_useragent, поможет ли это?

Comment: @ЕгорКопица не уверен что он тут на что-то влияет (да, при парсинге его лучше указывать) как я и писал выше нужно проводить более длительные исследования чтобы найти способ обхода, теоретически способ есть почти всегда

Comment: @DaniilLoban, а не подскажите откуда этот сайт перед вообще данные по ценам, по сути они же тоже откуда то выгружают данные

Comment: чтобы посмотреть все обращения из браузера нужно нажать F12 (инструменты разработчика) и выбрать вкладку network (сеть) а вней подвкладку All (любые запросы) однако по передаваемым запросам ничего явного не видно (там гифка и js файл jquery) куки и дргугие хранилища так же ничего наводящего на мысль не содержат, возможно этот сайт рендерится на сервере и там же происходит работа с данными (ничего наружу не вываливая)